# Errors in PHP project when shifted from IIS to Apache server

Tags: php, apache, iis, webmatrix

I developed a php project in WebMatrix on IIS. In this project I accidently initialed same "session variable" twice.

```
     Example: File - a.php

     <?php
     $_Session['one'];
     include 'b.php';
     ...........
     ...........
     ...........
     ...........
     ?>

     Example: File - b.php

     <?php
     $_Session['one'];
     ...........
     ...........
     ...........
     ...........
     ?>
```

When I run this project from Webmatrix(IIS server) this error wasn't shown but when I ran this project on Apache this error was displayed and I corrected my flaws.

```
   Warning on Apache:
   Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in D:/path/.
```

My question is that why this error was not shown earlier? Is it something related to IIS server or WebMatrix. I always need to be aware of the errors or warnings in the code so that I can get rid of them and the efficiency of the code is sustained, please do suggest me some ideal php develeopment tools which can catch even minor errors in my code.

Comment: Please add the error message to your question, so it's clear about which error you're speaking. Otherwise it's hard to give directions.

Comment: Sorry for the edits, actually the problem is with Session function and not the Include function... Complete details posted above.

Comment: In both files `a.php` and `b.php` are you doing a `session_start()`?

Comment: yes i did in both... On opening a.php i Get waring on apache but not on WebMAtrix(IIS)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure errors are being displayed and then try turning error_reporting all the way up at the beginning of the application.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also, be aware that Windows is **not** case-sensitive. You could say `include 'A.php'` or `include 'a.php'` and it would not care. However, when you put it on a Linux-based server, which is case-sensitive, it may not be able to find the file `A.php` if its actually `a.php`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you got errors because the first server was running PHP 4 and the second is PHP 5. Double-including a file containing functions will get different results in those versions. See the text just before example 6 in this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

EDIT: I believe the error messages generated in your edited post indicate something of a different nature.

For files that you want to make sure they are only included one time, use `include_once()`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

There are some situations where you may legitimately want to `include()` twice from a file. But because those situations are rare, it's best to use `include_once()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning on Apache:
   Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in D:/path/.
```

You can't start session again which is already started.

You need 1 session start at a.php when you include b.php it can use started session.

Its a warning and warning means its not good but php can fix this error and continue working.

Its all about error reporting level.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell if the error didn't occured on IIS or not. Only because it was not displayed or logged, does not mean it didn't occur. Please compare the [error reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting) `php.ini` configuration between both systems.

Another thing you should compare in configuration is if [session auto-start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) had been enabled on the old or new system or not. This might be triggering your error, but it's only a guess. As written the error might have been already on the old system but just was unnoticed.

Comment: Don't call `session_start` when you are already using session auto start. That's your error. Remove it from the code and you should be fine.

Comment: When i run a.php on Webmatrix no warning displays and vice versa on Wamp

Comment: The warning is only displayed if warning display is configured *and* if `session_start` is called. If any of those two is not the case, you won't see the warning.